# Setting up a AMI linux micro instance with apache, java, tomcat, mysql

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to setup my first Linux environment on the amazon cloud but seem to be missing something. I have zero experience with Linux, so a complete newbie.

What I've done thus far.

> ```
> 1. I've created the Linux instance. 
> 2. I was able to SSH in with putty.
> 3. installed jdk 7 using yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
> 4. installed tomcat using yum install tomcat7
> 5. installed mysql using yum install mysql55
> 6. I started tomcat using /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
> ```

When I open a new page in my browser and go to my ip, I do not see the tomcat page?

Do I need to install apache2? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Lastly, what else would I need to do in order to deploy my first a jar to tomcat?

If anybody knows of a step by step tutorial, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found some really nice documentation on this.

> http://in4ray.blogspot.com/2012/04/create-amazon-web-services-account.html

Comment: This does not address anything within your question above.

Comment: @MarkAtanislav How do you figure it doesn't? It provided an excellent guide to get an AMI instance up and running with tomcat. I was up and running within 15 mins after following that guide. Read past page one by clicking the next link in the last paragraph and you'll find the entire configuration.

Comment: Your question is: "When I open a new page in my browser and go to my ip, I do not see the tomcat page? Do I need to install apache2? If so, how do I go about doing that?Lastly, what else would I need to do in order to deploy my first a jar to tomcat?"

You linked to a page on setting up an AWS account. If you like the third page and it answers your actual question, link to that page. Which, for everyone who will find this, http://in4ray.blogspot.com/2012/04/install-tomcat-7-on-amazon-linux.html

Comment: There use to be multiple links until some one edited my answer and if you read my title, setting up ami Linux instance with tomcat mysql so the link provides excellent instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer based on my previous experience, upload your application to the linux server using scp, syntax (scp -i your_ssh_key.pem user_name@ip_address.com:/home/) and move that app to your tomcat7 webapp folder, mostly in etc/tomcat7/webapp/ (I am not sure though) and rename your app to ROOT first so that when ever you hit the URL it will load your app. You can also see the ROOT folder which already exists. You have to replace with your application and restart the tomcat7 server. Hope it should work. BTW can u mention which flavor of linux are u running, like ubuntu, centos or amazon linux etc?

Comment: I'm using amazon linux and used iptables to forward port 80 to 8080 as I've been told it's a much more secure way of handing port 80 rather than moving tomcat into root. I'm now having an issue opening tomcat-users.xml, it claims file can't not be found although I'm able to see it within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving this to https://serverfault.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ as you will likely have better help in deploying Tomcat, MySQL, and any additional dependencies.